# Application developed for Apple Watch should or should not need to synch with iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

I would like to know that Application developed for Apple Watch should need to synch with iPhone/iPad or we can develop the app only for Apple Watch without looking for iPhone/iPad?
Warmly welcome your answers.

Regards,
Sohaib

Comment: yes you have to sync your iwatch with applciation read this [link](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Chirag. Highly Appreciating, My question is, Can we not able to build the application only for apple watch?

Comment: Apple Watch requires the presence of an iPhone to run third-party apps. To create a third-party app, you need two separate bundles: a WatchKit app (that runs on Apple Watch) and a WatchKit extension (that runs on the user’s iPhone). this thing is write in "Developing for Apple Watch" document read this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html)

Comment: Alright, Thanks a lot. Another question related to this is , "Do we need to create iPhone app as well while developing apple watch application?"

Regards,
Sohaib

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a WatchKit app, you must implement iPhone app, too.

However, they don't need to be synchronized, as you can see in Battery Adviser (by Applestan) and iCalc (by Seyyed Parsa Neshaei) apps on the App Store. The iPhone and iPad versions of this apps are mandatory to install and available, but it doesn't sync with the Apple Watch. They both do the same, but without connecting to each other and sharing data.